# Quote-unquote idiom in Julia & concatenating Expr objects

Tags: macros, metaprogramming, julia

I'd like to write a simple macro that shows the names & values of variables. In Common Lisp it would be

```
(defmacro dprint (&rest vars)
  `(progn
    ,@(loop for v in vars
            collect `(format t "~a: ~a~%" ',v ,v))))
```

In Julia I had two problems writing this:

1. How can I collect the generated `Expr` objects into a block? (In Lisp, this is done by splicing the list with `,@` into `progn`.) The best I could come up with is to create an `Expr(:block)`, and set its `args` to the list, but this is far from elegant.
2. I need to use both the name and the value of the variable. Interpolation inside strings and quoted expressions both use `$`, which complicates the issue, but even if I use `string` for concatenation, I can 't print the variable's name - at least `:($v)` does not do the same as `',v` in CL...

My current macro looks like this:

```
macro dprint(vars...)
  ex = Expr(:block)
  ex.args = [:(println(string(:($v), " = ", $v))) for v in vars]
  ex
end
```

Looking at a macroexpansion shows the problem:

```
julia> macroexpand(:(@dprint x y))
quote 
    println(string(v," = ",x))
    println(string(v," = ",y))
end
```

I would like to get

```
quote 
    println(string(:x," = ",x))
    println(string(:y," = ",y))
end
```

Any hints?

EDIT: Combining the answers, the solution seems to be the following:

```
macro dprint(vars...)
  quote
    $([:(println(string($(Meta.quot(v)), " = ", $v))) for v in vars]...)
  end
end
```

... i.e., using `$(Meta.quot(v))` to the effect of `',v`, and `$(expr...)` for `,@expr`. Thank you again!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the `@show` macro already exists for this. It is helpful to be able to implement it yourself, so later you can do other likes like make one that will show the size of an Array..

For your particular variant:
Answer is `Meta.quot`,

```
macro dprint(vars...)
     ex = Expr(:block)
     ex.args = [:(println($(Meta.quot(v)), " = ", $v)) for v in vars]
     ex
end
```

See with:

```
julia> a=2; b=3;

julia> @dprint a
a = 2

julia> @dprint a b
a = 2
b = 3
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a more elegant way to create a block? (First part of my question)

Comment: To answer my question, looking at julia/base/show.jl, they use the same method, except that they `push!` incrementally to `ex.args`, so in Julia this must be the idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: `Expr(:block)` and `quote end` are equivalent, but `quote end` will retain line number information.

Comment: The equivalent of `quote` in common lisp is `QuoteNode`, not `Meta.quot`. The difference is, however, very subtle and not usually important.

Comment: @vukung: There is the option of:
`macro dprint(vars...)
     Expr(:block ,(:(println($(Meta.quot(v)), " = ", $v)) for v in vars)...)
end`

Which is really idk it that is nicer or not.

Answer (score 4):

oxinabox's answer is good, but I should mention the equivalent to `,@x` is `$(x...)` (this is the other part of your question).

For instance, consider the macro

```
macro _begin(); esc(:begin); end

macro @_begin()(args...)
    quote
        $(args...)
    end |> esc
end
```

and invocation

```
@begin x=1 y=2 x*y
```

which (though dubiously readable) produces the expected result `2`. (The `@_begin` macro is not part of the example; it is required however because `begin` is a reserved word, so one needs a macro to access the symbol directly.)

Note

```
julia> macroexpand(:(@begin 1 2 3))
quote  # REPL[1], line 5:
    1
    2
    3
end
```

I consider this more readable, personally, than pushing to the `.args` array.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that answers the first part.